# ag-grid-angular not resizing dynamically

Tags: angular

In Angualr, I have created grid using ag-grid-angular. After the grid is created, rendered and displayed, if a user resizes the browser width, the columns do not get resized. IF the width the decreased, it does not take min width of column and if browser width is increased then it leaves blank space on the right. User has to refresh to fit the column again. How can I do without user refreshing?

Solutions I tried but did not work:

- Adding width to parent container

```
<div style="width: 100%;" class="ag-theme-alpine">
 <ag-grid-angular [gridOptions]="gridOptions"></ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

- GridOptions

```
gridOptions = {
  domLayout: 'autoHeight',
  // Other grid options...
};
```

- Responsive layout

```
onGridReady(params) {
  params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
}
```

- Overriding CSS

```
.ag-center-cols-container { width: 100% !important; }
```